# Get into Intellij debug-view without actually starting the debugger?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

Intellij is driving me crazy... is there any way I can open the debugs-view (so I can see a list of breakpoints, and edit them) without actually having to launch a program in debug-mode?

If there is a way or button or short-cut, I have failed to see it till now.

---

After finding my breakpoints thanks to Bohuslav Burghardt, is there a way to mute them all without the debug-pane being visible?

Comment: The usual shortcut is alt-5, or ctrl-tab and then 5, but it doesnt seem to work if debug pane is closed...

Comment: See my updated answer for the solution to muting all breakpoints

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable the *Favorites* tool Window

- View -> Tool Windows -> Favorites
- Or using keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>)

This will show you the Favorites tool window, which contains your bookmarks and breakpoints.

You can edit breakpoint by right clicking on it and choosing Edit breakpoint.

**Update**

As for muting all the breakpoints without the debug panel being visible. You have two choices:

- Hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and search for Mute breakpoints (invoke this action again to unmute the breakpoints)
- Go to *Settings/Keymap* and bind a keyboard shortcut to the *Mute Breakpoints* action

Comment: Ahhh, that's at least a great start... embarrassingly, I kept staring at that favourites-panel, wondering what it did, never realising it showed breakpoints!

Comment: Thank you! You just made my life a lot easier :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) By the way I also noticed that when you mute the breakpoints, their appearance stays the same, which makes it hard to tell if they are muted. I created this issue for this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-132025. So if it bothers you too, feel free to vote for it :)